# SKLabelNode fade out in sprite scene

Tags: sprite-kit

I have an SKLabelNode that I am adding to my scene. I want it to fade out in 3 seconds and so it isn't visible anymore. How would I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4):

You can run an action:

```
[self.labelNode runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0 duration:3.0] completion:^{
   [self.labelNode removeFromParent];
}]
```

You can leave off the completion block if you don't want to remove it from the scene when you're done.